# Path finding in Complete Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, algorithm, pathfinding

I have the following Complete Graph with random labels on its edges

```
W = {1, 2, 3}; 
n = 5; 
el = EdgeList[CompleteGraph[n]]; 
g = 
 CompleteGraph[n, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  EdgeLabels -> 
   Table[el[[i]] -> RandomChoice[W], {i, Length[el]}]]
```

My goal is to find the number of paths `path = {1, 2, 3}` in it.

I already have a function

```
label[graph_, edges_] := First@Cases[Options[g, EdgeLabels], Rule[UndirectedEdge @@ Sort[edges], lbl_] :> lbl, Infinity]
```

which gives the edge label between 2 vertices (e.g. `label[g,{1,2}]` gives the label between vertices 1 and 2).

I've only come up with something like this

```
For[i = 1, i < n + 1, i++,
  For[j = i + 1, j < n + 1, j++,
   If[label[g, {i, j}] == path[[1]],
    For[k = j + 1, k < n + 1, k++,
     If[label[g, {j, k}] == path[[2]],
      For[t = 1, t < n + 1, t++,
       If[
        t != j && t != k && i != j && j != k && 
         label[g, {k, t}] == path[[3]],
        {d++}, d = d]]]]]]];
AppendTo[modellingResult, d];
```

I've tried my best to optimize the solution but it's either doesn't find all required paths or takes too long (like really long) to find the solution.

Edit:
To clarify what I've meant, path {1,2,3} means path between 4 vertices with label 1 between first and second, label 2 between second and third, label 3 between third and fourth.

Comment: Isn't this a trivial problem though? In a complete graph, any permutation of any vertex subset forms a path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 ClearAll[wWalks]
 wWalks[g_, wpath_] := Module[{dg = DirectedGraph @ g, edgetuples}, 
   edgetuples = Tuples[EdgeList[dg, _?(Function[e, 
       PropertyValue[{dg, e}, EdgeLabels] == #])] & /@ wpath];
   PadRight[VertexList @ #, 1 + Length @ wpath, "Periodic"] & /@ 
    Select[And @@ Equal @@@ Partition[#[[2 ;; -2]], 2] & @ Flatten @ (List @@@ #)&]@
      edgetuples]
```

***Examples:***

```
W = {1, 2, 3}; 
n = 5; 

SeedRandom[7]
g1 = CompleteGraph[n, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
      VertexSize -> .15, EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> RandomChoice[W]}]
```

[image]

```
wWalks[g1, {1, 2, 3}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 4, 5, 2}, {1, 4, 5, 3}, {2, 4, 5, 2}, {2, 4, 5, 3}, {4, 1, 2, 5}, 
>  {4, 1, 3, 4}, {4, 1, 3, 5}, {4, 1, 5, 2}, {4, 1, 5, 3}, 
>  {4, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 2, 3, 5}}
> ```

```
BarChart[Labeled[Length[wWalks[g1, #]], #, Axis] & /@ 
   Permutations[{1, 2, 3}], ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> 14]
```

[image]

```
Show[g1, 
   Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1], 
      VertexStyle -> {_ -> Opacity[0],
          #[[1]] -> Directive[EdgeForm[{Thick, Darker@Red}], 
               FaceForm[{Opacity[.5], Red}]],
          #[[-1]] -> Directive[EdgeForm[{Thick, Darker@Gray}], 
               FaceForm[{Opacity[.5], Gray}]]}, 
      VertexSize -> {_ -> .15, Alternatives @@ #[[{1, -1}]] -> .2}, 
      EdgeStyle -> Directive[Arrowheads[{{.08, .4}}], AbsoluteThickness[2], Red], 
      VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[g1][[DeleteDuplicates@#]], 
      EdgeShapeFunction -> "CurvedEdge"], 
    PlotLabel -> Style[#, 16, Black], ImageSize -> 300] & /@ wWalks[g1, {1, 2, 3}] // 
   Multicolumn[#, 4, Dividers -> All, Appearance -> "Horizontal"] &
```

[image]

Replace `wWalks[g1, {1, 2, 3}]` above with `wWalks[g1, {1, 2, 3, 2, 1}]` to get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need not reinvent the wheel. If I correctly understand your "My goal is to find the number of paths path = {1, 2, 3} in it", the `FindPath` command does the job.

```
W = {1, 2, 3};n = 5; $RecursionLimit = 10^4;el = EdgeList[CompleteGraph[n]];
g = CompleteGraph[n, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
EdgeLabels -> Table[el[[i]] -> RandomChoice[W], {i, Length[el]}]]; 
Table[FindPath[g, k, j, Infinity, All] , {k, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 5}]
```

I leave on your own to choose the required paths.

Comment: To clarify what I've meant, path {1,2,3} means path between 4 vertices with label 1 between first and second, label 2 between second and third, label 3 between third and fourth. Is it possible to apply ‘‘‘FindPath‘‘‘ command for more than two vertices?

Comment: Sorry, still don't understand what you want. You asked " Is it possible to apply `FindPath` command for more than two vertices?". Likely no.

Comment: Basically, my whole question is how can I find the number of paths that I've described in my first comment. Still can't figure out how ```FindPath``` command can help me.

Comment: @mclord Please edit the top post and include what you said in your first comment here. Now I understand what you want, but it's not at all clear by reading only the top post.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive approach to generate the walks:

```
ClearAll[nextEdges, addEdge, startWith, eWalks, vWalks]

nextEdges[g_] := AssociationThread[VertexList[g], 
  Thread[DirectedEdge[#, AdjacencyList[g][[#]]]] & /@ VertexList[g]]

addEdge[g_, wpath_][edges_] := Append[edges, #] & /@ 
  (Select[nextEdges[g]@edges[[-1, -1]], PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeLabels] == 
      wpath[[1 + EdgeCount @ edges]] &])

startWith[g_, wpath_] := List /@ 
   EdgeList[g, _?(PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeLabels] == wpath[[1]] &)]

eWalks[g_, wpath_] := Nest[Catenate @* Map[addEdge[g, wpath]], startWith[g, wpath], 
  Length @ wpath - 1]

vWalks[g_, wpath_] := Map[PadRight[VertexList@#, 1 + Length @ wpath, "Periodic"] &] @
  eWalks[g, wpath]
```

***Examples:***

```
W = {1, 2, 3}; 
n = 5; 

SeedRandom[7]
g1 = CompleteGraph[n, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
      VertexSize -> .15, EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> RandomChoice[W]}];

vWalks[DirectedGraph @ g1, {1, 2, 3}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 4, 5, 2}, {1, 4, 5, 3}, {2, 4, 5, 2}, {2, 4, 5, 3}, 
>  {4, 1, 2, 5}, {4, 1, 3, 4}, {4, 1, 3, 5}, {4, 1, 5, 2},
>  {4, 1, 5, 3}, {4, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 2, 3, 5}}
> ```

```
BarChart[Labeled[Length[vWalks[DirectedGraph @ g1, #]], #, Axis] & /@ 
  Permutations[{1, 2, 3}], ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> 14]
```

[image]

```
vWalks[DirectedGraph @ g1, {1, 2, 3, 2, 1}]
```

[image]

```
BarChart[Labeled[Length[vWalks[DirectedGraph @ g1, #]], 
    Rotate[Style[#, 12], -90 Degree], Axis] & /@ 
  Permutations[{1, 2, 3, 2, 1}], ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> 14]
```

[image]